Movie where one serial killer turns out to be 6 serial killers
I've posted on this page a similar question to this one a few days ago. I'm trying to identify this movie I watched a few years back but on the internet. The movie wasn't old, i would say they made it around 2008.
The plot is about a detective (could be a woman, or a man, or both), is trying to catch a serial killer. Most of the movie is just trying to get close to the serial killer, and they got a lot of suspects. The problem is that every single one of them has an alibi for at least one murder, so they can't really lock them up... Well, at the end when they are searching through one of the suspect's cabin, which is located I would say somewhere in Texas (I'm not from the US), they found a picture of 5 suspects on the same picture. Suspects seemed to make a system how to not get caught by the police. They thought everything is over, but the detective saw in the corner of the photo, a shadow of someone who is taking the picture.
Then there is some blurry part I can't recall at all, but I know that the girl is caught in the house by her father (an older man, not sure if her father), in the garage full of gas. She escaped and killed him. Finally everything was over, but at the end they show a scene, that one of the detectives was talking to that older guy, who said to him, that he should continue the legend of killings. 
There this is far more informative than the last one, I think this one won't be a problem to identify.

Uh, why did you just delete the other question? Is this one actually asking for the same movie? If yes, then you could just have edited any further details into the previous question. There's no need to reask a question just because of some new information, this just wastes all the effort spent on the existing question. You also might want to take a look at the [tour] and the [help] to get a better grip of how this site works.

You're after Hunt for the Labyrinth Killer, though a few details are a bit off (it's from 2013, for one).

Young, ace assistant DA, Shelby Cook, works with driven cop, Mike Holland, to catch Daedalus, a serial killer infamous for luring his victims to their deaths through labyrinth traps. Three innocent men have already taken the fall for Daedalus and when Daedalus strikes again, Shelby finds herself defending the latest man accused, a retired and respected judge--who also happens to be her own father.

It's 3 suspects, not 5, and they find a picture of all 3 in one suspect's trailer. But someone later realizes that there's a shadow in the picture of the person who took it. Turns out Shelby's father really is the killer and he tries to gas her in a closed garage, but she escapes and kills him. In a final twist, it's reveald that her dad told Mike, a secret fan of the killer, to carry on his legacy.  


Thank you, this is the one i've been looking for, even though it's a pretty stupid movie. Even now when i watch it i really don't remember any of their faces, not even the title, so probably the reason , why i couldn't remember it. Again, thank you.
